# AVCaptureSession zoom in feature while clicking images

Tags: ios, zooming, avcapturesession, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have implemented a camera using AVCaptureSession I want to implement pinch gesture to allow user to zoom and take images.

I have gone through various links but of no help,How can I go about it?